# Runtime error while sending Rest request via VBA

Tags: vba, rest

I send `Rest request` to `HTTP server` via `VBA script` looking like this:

```vb
    HTTP.Open "PUT", rUrl, True
    HTTP.SetRequestHeader "Host", rHost
    HTTP.SetRequestHeader "Authorization", "Bearer " + rToken
    HTTP.SetRequestHeader "Content-Length", Len(rBody)
    HTTP.send rBody
```

Everything works fine on Windows 10 (64bit), but I get a runtime error on Windows 7 (64bit) at the line `HTTP.send rBody`:

[image: Error image]

Do you know what could cause this error?

Comment: Have you checked for any MISSING reference when launched in Windows 7?

Comment: No. There are no any checked missing libraries on win7 computer